# Need help to create a function that will suggest words from a given list

Tags: python

I would like to create a function that takes in a list with a bunch of words, then I will give like half a word and it will give me the whole-word.

Basically, if the input is "ca" then the output will be "car" or "win" gives "window" and so on. My idea is to iterate through every letter in the word I put in and check if it matches.

In my code below, what I tried to do was to first loop through the word and each letter in the word and then loop through the list, and then I tried to
match two letters. If it matches it will print that word. But I get the error message `string index out of range`.

And I kind of feel like this is not optimal at all to just match only two letters, if the list was longer, like a dictionary, it might cause issues.

```
list_words = ["car","telephone","watch","window","laptop","lamp"]
word = "ca"
def autocomplete():
    for letter in word:
        i = 0
        while i < len(list_words):
            if letter[0] == list_words[i][0] and letter[1] == list_words[i][1]:
                return list_word[i]
            i += 1
print(autocomplete())
```

Comment: You could really simplify this if you used [`startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know this existed, thank you so much, I will try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by trying to access `letter[1]`. Because of the `for letter in word` loop, `letter` is set to a string containing an individual letter from `word`, thus `letter[1]` will result in an error.

Most likely, you meant to access `word[0]` and `word[1]`, not `letter[0]` and `letter[1]`. Try the following code:

```
list_words = ["car","telephone","watch","window","laptop","lamp"]
word = "ca"
def autocomplete():
    for letter in word:
        i = 0
        while i < len(list_words):
            if word[0] == list_words[i][0] and word[1] == list_words[i][1]:
                return list_words[i]
            i += 1
print(autocomplete())
```

By performing this change, you no longer even need the `for letter in word` loop, thus you can change your code to this:

```
list_words = ["car","telephone","watch","window","laptop","lamp"]
word = "ca"
def autocomplete():
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_words):
        if word[0] == list_words[i][0] and word[1] == list_words[i][1]:
            return list_words[i]
        i += 1
print(autocomplete())
```

As Random Davis [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66127825/need-help-to-create-a-function-that-will-suggest-words-from-a-given-list#comment116912378_66127825), there's actually a builtin function, `startswith`, that can simplify your code even further. In the below code, rather than checking if the first and second character of `word` match the first and second character of `list_words[i]`, it will simply check if `list_words[i]` begins with `word`.

```
list_words = ["car","telephone","watch","window","laptop","lamp"]
word = "ca"
def autocomplete():
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_words):
        if list_words[i].startswith(word):
            return list_words[i]
        i += 1
print(autocomplete())
```

Comment: Damn, thanks for the help, really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`letter` is an individual letter of your partial word, just as you specified.
Just what do you think you're going to get when you check letter[1]?  That's out of range.

Your loop logic is built for `word`, not `letter`.  To fix that:

```
for match in list_words:
    if match.startswith(word):
        return match
return "FAILED"
```